# Evaluating Cauchy's integral $ \int _{|z+1|=1}\frac{1}{(z+1)\sin(z^{2}+z+1)}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to solve the following Cauchy's integral   $$ \int _{|z+1|=1}\frac{1}{(z+1)\sin(z^{2}+z+1)}dz$$

$|z+1|=1 \Rightarrow |x+1+iy|=1\Rightarrow\sqrt{(x+1)^{2}+(iy)^{2}}=1 \Rightarrow(x+1)^{2}+(iy)^{2}=1^{2}
$

on the other hand

$(z+1)sin(z^{2}+z+1)= 0 \Rightarrow  (z+1)=0 \rightarrow z=-1$ or $sin(z^{2}+z+1)= 0$ but $sin=0  $ only $sin(0)$ and $(z^{2}+z+1)>0$

How do I find the $Z_{0}$ to use the formula $\oint \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_{0})}= 2\pi if(z_{0})$

Even getting $z_{0}$ and evaluating it at f (z) would still be 1, right?

Comment: a) $\sin \pi$ is also $0$ and b) $z^2+z+1 > 0$ is meaningless because it's a complex number.

Comment: True $z^{2}-z-1=0 \rightarrow z= -\frac{1}{2}- i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Comment: Things might be easier if you substitute $w=z+1$ to translate the center of the circle to the origin.